# A bounded, self-adjoint, positive operator $T$ induces a positive semidefinite quadratic form $\langle Tx,x\rangle$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T\in \mathcal B(H)$ be a *bounded, self-adjoint* linear operator that is *positive* in the sense that $\sigma(T) \subset [0,\infty)$.

> Is there an elementary method of proving that $T$ induces a positive semidefinite quadratic form, i.e.
>   $$
> \langle Tx,x\rangle \ge 0
> $$
>   for all $x\in H$?

The proof of this statement (and its converse) can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007137/spectrum-of-self-adjoint-operators). However, while the converse can be proved by an elementary mean, the proof of the statement that I want relies on the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators. I want to know if there is a more rudimentary way to do it (i.e. without using these high-tech theorems).

Comment: Are you ok with $C^*$-algebraic techniques?

Comment: [Kato, p.268](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf#page=291), Corollary 3.3 relates the spectrum to the numerical range.

Comment: @Aweygan Yes, that's fine with me. I guess it'd be kind of natural in some sense since we're talking about the spectrum anyway.

Comment: @KeithMcClary That is an interesting approach, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem:** Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert Space $H$. Then $\lambda=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ is in the spectrum of $T$.
Therefore, if $\sigma(T)\subseteq[0,\infty)$, then $\langle Tx,x\rangle \ge 0$ for all $x$.

**Proof:** Suppose $T$ is bounded and self-adjoint with $\lambda = \inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$. Then $\langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle \ge 0$, which is enough to imply that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds for the form $[x,y] = \langle (T-\lambda I)x,y\rangle$. Writing this out,
$$
          |[x,y]|^2 \le [x,x][y,y] \\
          |\langle (T-\lambda I)x,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle(T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle\langle (T-\lambda I)y,y\rangle
$$
Now let $y=(T-\lambda I)x$:
$$
       \|(T-\lambda I)x\|^4 \le \langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle\|T-\lambda I\|\|(T-\lambda I)x\|^2 \\
       \|(T-\lambda I)x\|^2 \le \|T-\lambda I\|\langle (T-\lambda I)x,x\rangle 
$$
Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of unit vectors such that $\lim_n\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle=\lambda$. It follows that $\lim_n \|(T-\lambda I)x_n\|=0$, which puts $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$. $\;\;\blacksquare$

Comment: Isn't this the converse of what I asked?

Comment: @BigbearZzz : I fixed this. Take another look.

Comment: Looks very good now, thanks!

Comment: $[\cdot ,\cdot ]$ is almost an inner product. Positeveness doesn't hold. Here is a proof that Cauchy Schwarz holds in this other context: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2548691/1015934